# How to get cluster from a node?

Tags: c++, windows, cluster-computing

I have a node name and I need to be able to get a cluster from that node name. On MSDN there is a `GetClusterFromNode` function which will do that, but it works with node handle, which apparently I dont have at that moment. So what is the way to get a cluster of node by its name using c++ ?

Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `OpenCluster` with `NULL` parameter returned cluster handle for local PC, which was fine in my case.